# Querying with > (greater than) returns records >= (greater than or equal to)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Can someone explain why the following query:

```
> modified_after = DateTime.parse "2012-12-06T17:40:36+00:00"
> Contact.unscoped.where("updated_at > :time OR deleted_at > :time", {:time => modified_after})
```

also returns records with `updated_at` equal to `modified_after`:

```
Contact Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "contacts".* FROM "contacts" WHERE (updated_at > '2012-12-06 17:40:36' OR deleted_at > '2012-12-06 17:40:36') => [
#<Contact id: 28, first_name: "John", last_name: "A", deleted_at: nil, created_at: "2012-12-06 17:40:36", updated_at: "2012-12-06 17:40:36", email: nil, notes: nil>, 
#<Contact id: 29, first_name: "Mark", last_name: "B", deleted_at: nil, created_at: "2012-12-06 17:40:36", updated_at: "2012-12-06 17:40:36", email: nil, notes: nil>,
 #<Contact id: 30, first_name: "Michael", last_name: "C", deleted_at: nil, created_at: "2012-12-06 17:40:36", updated_at: "2012-12-06 17:40:36", email: nil, notes: nil>
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be that those times are milliseconds greater than the query time.  What version of Rails are you running?  Check out this bug and see if it is related: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/7385

Comment: Had Rails 3.2.8. Upgraded to 3.2.9 and everything works as expected. Thanks!